# Dropdownlist value always returns zero in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the sample of the model class

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Department is required")]
[Display(Name = "Department")]
public int SelectedValue { get; set; }


[Required(ErrorMessage = "Department is required")]
[Display(Name = "Department")]
public List<Department> RoleList { get; set; }
```

This is the view

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleList, new SelectList(Model.RoleList,"ID", "RoleName","1"), "Please Choose a Department", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedValue, "",new { @class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

The list is populated perfectly from the database. Now when i select the item on the list, the select value has to be sent to the controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    int Selectedvalue = model.SelectedValue;
    if (ModelState.IsValid && (model.SelectedValue).ToString() != "0")
    {
```

Here i have made a selection

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: We can't see your error.

Comment: @MattSpinks , it has been solved

Answer (score 3):

You should change it

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleList, new SelectList(Model.RoleList,"ID", "RoleName","1"), "Please Choose a Department", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

To

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.RoleList,"ID", "RoleName","1"), "Please Choose a Department", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

The first parameter of the `DropDownListFor` should be selected value in model. In your case, this property is `Model.SelectedValue` not `Model.RoleList`.

Comment: In addition you can remove the Required attribute from RoleList becuase it is not POST'ed to the server and the Display attribute because are displaying that property, you are displaying the property of SelectedValue